# D3 Tree-Interactive how to detect clicks on nodes both parents and childeren

Tags: treeview, d3.js

Trying to receive a callback from clicks on node. Currently the example expands a parent node if you click on it to show the children nodes. I would like to be able to click on the child node and receive a call independent from the parent node clicks. But I would need to know which child node was clicked as well. How best would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events/) css attribute on the parent elements:

```
d3.selectAll(_parents_).style("pointer-events","none");
```

and give the child nodes an on click function:

```
d3.selectAll(_children_).on("click", _somefunction_);
```

Not exactly sure if this is what you were asking, otherwise I'd suggest creating a jsfiddle to describe your intentions a little better